# How do I check if a value is assigned to an int in c#?

Tags: c#

`int x` might not have an assignment.  How do I detect that?  What value does int hold when it is unassigned?

This gives me a warning in Visual Studio:

```
public SomeMethod(int x) {
    if (x == null) {
    /* VS throws a warning:
    'The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type 'int' 
     is never equal to 'null' of type 'int' */
    };
}
```

This also gives me a warning in Visual Studio:

```
public SomeMethod(int? x) { 
    // declaring int 'Nullable' does not fix the warning.
    if (x == null) {
    // Same warning.
    };
}
```

Likewise:

```
public SomeMethod(int? x) {
    if (!x.HasValue) { 
    //  This does not work either.
    };
}
```

Comment: What "warnings" are you getting for the last two examples?

Comment: int is a value type, so it is by default initialized with zero. All reference types are initialized with null

Comment: There is no way to pass null value to the value type. If you try to pass null then it will throw an exception.

Comment: @SBI The warning is in the commented-out part of the first example, but the text is 'The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type 'int' is never equal to 'null' of type 'int'

Comment: I can't reproduce the warning you supposedly get with the middle example. Admittedly it's not a valid *method* because it has no return type, and it's very odd to have an empty statement after the `if` statement (get rid of the semi-colon), but a method of `public void SomeMethod(int? x) { if (x == null) { } }` compiles for me with no warnings.

Answer (score 17):

> int x might not have an assignment.

That's simply not true. In your case, `x` is a parameter - it's "definitely assigned" from the start of the method, in specification terminology. When someone calls the method, they *have* to provide a value. There's no concept of the value not being assigned.

If you want to represent a parameter which may not have a meaningful `int` value, you should use `Nullable<int>`, aka `int?`:

```
public void DoSomething(int? x)
{
    if (x == null)
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        // Or whatever
        Console.WriteLine(x.Value);
    }
}
```

As of C# 4, you could then give the parameter a default value of `null` if you want to be able to call it as just `foo.DoSomething()` without providing a value. You couldn't distinguish between that and `foo.DoSomething(null)` though.

Answer (score 2):

In your case the best solution probably would be to use a default value for the parameter like this, so that when the parameter is null, the code does not throw an error and also the compiler will not show any warning -

```
    public void test(int? x){
        if (x == null)
        {
            Console.Write("test");
        }
    }

    public void testA(int? x = null)
    {
        if (x == null)
        {
            Console.Write("test");
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Program();
        p.test(null);
        p.testA();
    }
```

But the code -

```
public SomeMethod(int x) {
    if (x == null) {
    /* Never happens because 'The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type 'int' is never equal to 'null' of type 'int' */
    };
}
```

will always show warning because the default value for `int` is `0`, not `null` as mentioned here -

[C# Primitive Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711900%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

And thus the the value for `x == null` is always false.

Comment: I should have clarified that public void test(int? x) does not work either.

Comment: I checked my outputs with VS and pretty sure both works... I am out right now, will post the build log later...